# Laravel Nova show Dashboard based on Role

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Within my users Table I have different roles. I have two different Dashboards and want to show the Dashboard based on thier roles. But I dont understand how the canSeeWhen method from laravel works?

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/customization/dashboards.html#defining-dashboards

Lets say I have the roles Admin and editor and trader.

I have the Admin Dashboard, this should be available for the admins and editors and I have the trader dashboard, this should be available for the traders.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple options, you can use the `canSee` method and the `canSeeWhen` method.

The `canSee` method accepts a callback and based on the return true or false it will show the dashboard.

example:

```php
public function dashboards()
{
    return [
        .....
        ExampleDashboard::make()->canSee(function ($request) {
            return $request->user()->role == 'admin'
        }),
    ];
}
```

In the above example, when the user role property is equal to 'admin' they see the dashboard.

When using the `canSeeWhen` it actually uses the policy system from laravel, maybe you are making a dashboard based on all user data then you want to know that the user that is viewing the data is also authorized to viewany user.

Then you could do something like this:

```php
public function dashboards()
{
    return [
        ...
        ExampleDashboard::make()->canSeeWhen('viewAny', \App\Models\User::class),
    ];
}
```

[Read more about the policies](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization)